# How to write multiple condifitonal functions in Shiny app R?

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

gim really new to coding and have no idea about it. a help would be really appreciated.

in Shiny R, if i were to have multiple conditional functions, how do i write it? is this correct?

```
## Function to calculate premium
```

PremCalc = function(Age,IR,Type, Benefit, Payable, Term, SumAssured){

if(Type == "Policyholder X", Benefit == "Pure Endowment", Payable == "Immediately on death") {*formulas})

***EDITED***

Someone has already answered the question by usin either || or &&, onto another question, what if i dont use the else if? can i write something like:

if(Type == "Policyholder X", Benefit == "Pure Endowment", Payable == "Immediately on death") {*formulas})

if(Type == "Policyholder Y", Benefit == "Endowment Assurance", Payable == "At the end year of death") {*formulas})

if(Type == "Policyholder X", Benefit == "Term Assurance", Payable == "Immediately on death") {*formulas})

,etc. with all the possible choices available LOL..

Comment: No - use `&&` or `||` instead of the commas - depending on the required logic. Please see `?\`&&\`` and [this chapter](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html?q=help#getting-help) of `mastering shiny`.

Comment: thank you so so much for the help! i have another question edited in my question box as well, do u mind answering :)